# Sharepoint Workflows - Task Process

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

Can someone explain to me how the task process works? I have read

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/use-the-task-process-editor-for-approval-workflows-HA101863538.aspx#_Toc264538566

but there are a couple of questions I have.

Within SharePoint Designer
How do the Overall task process behavior works compared to the single tasks? I am trying to understand the order of operations. It seems to me that the overall task process kicks off and runs and the individual steps run within the overall task process, sort of nested? with the single task processes having Pending, Expires, Deleted, Complete steps. So if a single task process completes, then does it hand back off to the overall task process and that code or logic runs?

To figure this out. I created a send email event on all the overall task process and single task process steps. Within the Single task process under Before Task is Assigned, it sends me an email with the step name in the subject. I get the following emails in this order:

1. Overall Task - Start
2. Overall Task - Running
     2a. Single Task - Before Task is Assigned.

If I delete the document, I would assume the Single Task - Deleted would kick in and I would get an email but I don't.... Thoughts?